# Getting a Method Object without Addressing the Method by Name

Tags: java, reflection, obfuscation

Is there a way to get a method object without having to use the Method's name to grab it?

For example I have the class:

```
class Car {

    public String drive();
    public String giveUp();
    public String fillUp();
}
```

I would like to create a `Map<String, Method>` of methods (aka: ("move", drive()), ("name", giveUp()), ....).

I'm not able to get the method object via name due to obfuscation being used. Is there a way to grab the method name without having to bind this?

I guess another way of asking this is:

For a class you have getClass(), is there an equivalent for methods? I'm looking for something allong the lines of giveUp.Method.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the irony of mis-spelling "obfuscation", please try and be careful not to generate mis-spelled tags, especially when you have auto-complete to help.

Comment: Hey I blame auto complete on that one.

Comment: hey why not except the methods from obfuscation? i.e. either you access the methods by name or you obfuscate, your two goals do not combine and pretending they do by working around is futile. In worst case, create a if(key) { // call method for key } else if(nextKey) {...}.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such construct as `Car.giveUp.method()` in Java, because methods are not "first-class citizens" like classes and objects.

Without knowing what the obfuscator does to your code, or adding additional information, you cannot distinguish the methods, because apart from their name, they have the same signature.

- Some obfuscators produce text files that map the original name to the obfuscated name, and you could use that map file to identify the obfuscated method at runtime.
- You could add an annotation to the method, like

  ```
  @MappedMethod("move")
  public String drive();
  ```

  with a self-written annotation `@MappedMethod` and a default attribute of type `String`. Then use reflection to get all methods and their annotations, and use the annotation value as key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Reflection to get all the methods.

```
Class<Car> clazz = Car.class;
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Them you iterate over methods and map them:

```
for(Method method: methods)
    map.put( method.getName(), method);
```

Comment: I've got a specific name of the methods, and I don't need all of the methods mapped. The goal is to have the map.get("name").invoke(...). Due to the obfuscator the method name will change anyways.